# Qt FrameBuffer Object don't render even vertices

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

I'm learning to use OpenGL in Qt with the `QOpenGLFramebufferObject`， and tried to draw a triangle using the following code:

In `render()` :

```
glUseProgram(m_program);
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,  // first 
     0.0f, -1.0f,  // second
     0.0f,  1.0f   // third  
};
unsigned int VAO;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), vertices);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
```

And the shaders are in `initShader()` :

```
const GLchar* vfSource[] = {
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPos;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "}\n\0"
};
const GLchar* fsSource[] = {
    "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0"
};
```

Only the first and third vertex rendered correctly. The second vertex were located in the center of my screen.

And if I changed the `vertices[]` to

```
-1.0f, -1.0f,  // 1
 0.0f, -1.0f,  // 2
 0.0f,  1.0f   // 3
 1.0f,  1.0f,  // 4
 1.0f,  0.0f   // 5
```

and the last line to

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 5);
```

The output is a triangle produced by the data in line 1 3 and 5.

I have no idea about what's wrong with this code. Anyone can help me?

If more code is needed, just let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenGL 3.3 Core Profile (which your shaders are targeting) doesn't allow you to draw directly from client memory. The last parameter of [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is a offset into the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. Setting it to something else than zero should trigger a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` when no `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is bound.

In order to get your example working your need to generate a Vertex Buffer Object (VBO) and attach it to the VAO.

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

Comment: Solved. Thanks a lot :)